# create a dynamic category-{id}.php template wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, categories

I am trying to find a way to dynamically create a category template when ever I create a new category.

For example: 
category-{id}.php

I can't find anyway of doing this. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a general category.php file and add code there. If you need different template for specific category, than use an if or switch statement to it, depending on the category, for example:

```
if (is_category( 'some-category' )) {
   echo 'this is some-category';
}
```

Comment: What I am try do to is create a physical file i.e category-38.php or category-39.php basically duplicating the category.php file and settings. This then will allow us to restructure the layout if that makes sense.

Comment: I understand, however this will be much harder to do than using if statements inside category.php. Also you must be very carefull how you do it, to avoid and security risks.
If you can shift the idea, to use single category file, you can still call template files for different categories with get_template_part(), if you really need to. But again, if you want to dynamicly create those as well, I am sadly not the person, who could offer you advice on this.